# The data shows null for LINQ Query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

```
var result = await (from data in _dbContext.MaterialInwardBarcodes
                            where data.VendorId == vendorId && data.Date >= fromDate && data.Date <= toDate
                            join product in _dbContext.Products on data.ProductId equals product.Id
                            where product.CategoryId == categoryId
                            join material in _dbContext.MaterialInwardDetails on new { ProductId = data.ProductId, MaterialInwardHeaderId = data.RefId } equals new { material.ProductId, material.MaterialInwardHeaderId } into materialGroup
                            from material in materialGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join barcode in _dbContext.BarcodePost on data.Barcode equals barcode.BarcodeNumber into barcodeGroup
                            from barcode in barcodeGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join returnDetails in _dbContext.MaterialReturnNoteDetails on barcode.RefId equals returnDetails.MaterialReturnNoteHeaderId into rDetailsGroup
                            from returnDetails in rDetailsGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join invoice in _dbContext.InvoiceHeader on barcode.RefId equals invoice.BucketId into invoiceGroup
                            from invoice in invoiceGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join iDetails in _dbContext.InvoiceDetails on invoice.Id equals iDetails.InvoiceHeaderId into iDetailsGroup
                            from iDetails in iDetailsGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            group new { data, material, iDetails, returnDetails } by new { data.Date, data.ProductId, data.Barcode } into grouped
                            select new VendorPaymentDetails()
                            {
                                Date = grouped.Key.Date,
                                ProductId = grouped.Key.ProductId,
                                PurchaseQty = grouped.Sum(x => (decimal?)x.material.Quantity ?? 0.0m),
                                ReturnQty = grouped.Sum(x => (decimal?)x.returnDetails.Quantity ?? 0.0m),
                                SaleQty = grouped.Sum(x => (decimal?)x.iDetails.Quantity ?? 0.0m)
                            }
                           ).ToListAsync();
```

This is the LINQ query I have written where I want to fetch PurchaseQty , ReturnQty , SaleQty but the data returns as Null what should changes should I make in the above LINQ query so I can fetch the data. It returns null due to ReturnQty If I fetch PurchaseQty and SaleQty it works perfectly

I have provided the SQL query which works

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('day', m."Date", 'UTC') AS "Date",
    m."ProductId",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN m0."Quantity" IS NOT NULL THEN m0."Quantity" ELSE 0 END), 0.0) AS "PurchaseQty",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN r0."Quantity" IS NOT NULL THEN r0."Quantity" ELSE 0 END), 0.0) AS "ReturnQty",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN i0."Quantity" IS NOT NULL THEN i0."Quantity" ELSE 0 END), 0.0) AS "SaleQty"
FROM "MaterialInwardBarcodes" AS m
LEFT JOIN "MaterialInwardDetails" AS m0 ON m."ProductId" = m0."ProductId" AND m."RefId" = m0."MaterialInwardHeaderId"
LEFT JOIN "BarcodePost" AS b ON m."Barcode" = b."BarcodeNumber"
LEFT JOIN "MaterialReturnNoteDetails" AS r0 ON b."RefId" = r0."MaterialReturnNoteHeaderId"
LEFT JOIN "InvoiceHeader" AS i ON b."RefId" = i."BucketId"
LEFT JOIN "InvoiceDetails" AS i0 ON i."Id" = i0."InvoiceHeaderId"
WHERE m."VendorId" = '52e4bd92-c9de-4d0a-87c7-80f45ce17117'
  AND date_trunc('day', m."Date", 'UTC') >= '2023-08-28T00:00:00Z'
  AND date_trunc('day', m."Date", 'UTC') <= '2023-08-31T00:00:00Z'
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', m."Date", 'UTC'), m."ProductId", m."Barcode"
```

Can someone convert this SQL query into LINQ. Or atleast provide me the changes to make in above LINQ query so the data returns exaact

In LINQ query the data returns Null as it fails to fetch for ReturnQty but if I comment out ReturnQty and check for PurchaseQty and SaleQty it fetches the data.

Comment: Isolate what part of code fails to return data.  Start by doing only one join and then keep adding to the code until it stops returning data.  Usually failures like this are do to joining strings with numbers. Or when you are joining string dates with DateTime objects.  See if removing the WHERE statement(s) returns data.

Comment: SQL queries can't be converted into LINQ. They can be *emulated*, but that requires knowledge of the class model. Also the exact Entity Framework version is relevant (please choose the appropriate tag). Additionally, define navigation properties, don't use the `join` statement.